# I want to sum every 7 rows in a worksheet and put the sum in different column & rows

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have never really used Excel before but this seems like it should be possible.

I have an ongoing document where I will be adding values every day, but what I want it to do for every 7 rows I want it to sum those values and add the sum of the 7 rows to a different column/row, e.g.,

Row B7:B14  Sum in D12
Row B15:B22 Sum in D13

And then when I start adding data into B23 I want it to add the sum to D14.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In D12, put

```
=SUM(OFFSET($B$7,(ROW()-12)*8,0,8,1))
```

and fill down column D as far as you want.  Note that B7:B14 is really 8 rows, not 7.  If you really want 7 rows (B7:B13), then change the two 8's to 7's in the formula.

Comment: Thank you for answering this, I've just come up with the same problem myself and your answer solved it.

Comment: Hi, this is not working for me as i don't understand what the (ROW()-12) is doing, I have run checks by selecting sum of 7 rows and get different numbers.

Comment: When you're in D12, ROW()-12 will be zero, so the offset is zero rows (0*8). When you're in D13, ROW()-12 is one, so the offset is eight rows (1*8). As you copy the formula down, the offset jumps 8 rows.

Comment: @DickKusleika lets say I have "sheet1" and "sheet2", how could I do the sum of every 7 rows, in my case it is 10 rows, and have the output on another sheet such as sheet 2.  I seem to be getting a REF error `=AVERAGE(OFFSET('sheet1'!$AE$9,(ROW()-9)*10,0,10,1))`

Comment: @DickKusleika nvm, so I put in `=AVERAGE(OFFSET('sheet1'!$AE$9,(ROW()-6)*10,0,10,1))` and that fixed my problem.  I realized that `ROW() - 6` references the cell you are entering in the function at.  and in that case, I was placing it in row 6 and pulling the data from row 9.