# I want to sum the next nth data points in Excel and store them in a separate column

Tags: excel

I am working on a project where I am using Excel to analyze several million data points. I've already converted my data into simple binary true and false. Now I need to sum 75,000 data points at a time and store them in a separate column. I think what I need to do is very similar to the result given to the linked question at the bottom of this post but I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to store the sum's properly.

For example, I want to take data points B1 through B75,000 and sum them and store them in D1. Then I want to sum B75,001 through B150,000 and store them in D2 and so on.

As mentioned, the result should be in a pretty similar form to that given in the linked question, I was mostly hoping someone could clarify what numbers I need to use in order to fix my offset problems and store the numbers in the right location. Thanks in advanced for any help you can give, I appreciate it.

[I want to sum every 7 rows in a worksheet and put the sum in different column & rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680350/i-want-to-sum-every-7-rows-in-a-worksheet-and-put-the-sum-in-different-column)

Comment: try `=SUM(OFFSET($B$1,(ROW()-1)*75000,0,75000,1))` in D1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the comment, I edited and simplified the answer. Try this out:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($B$1,(ROW()-1)*75000,0,75000,1))
```

*Edit: Heh, now I see it's the same as ZAT's comment, which was made when the question had the old ranges. :)*

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think I posted the wrong parameters the first time, all ranges should be the same size. So I think I actually want B1 through B75,000 then B75,001 through B150,000, etc.