# Sum every nth rows in Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

```
28      10 | 100
29      210
30    
40      20 | 84
41      130
42    
43      30 | 75
44      740
45    
46      40 | 73
47      220
```

How can I sum every 3 rows A29+A41+A44+A47+...
I tried various suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680350/i-want-to-sum-every-7-rows-in-a-worksheet-and-put-the-sum-in-different-column) and [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sum-every-nth-row.html) one but couldn't figured it out.

In addition, is there any way to extract the second part, to a different column, of the other rows? I mean 100, 84, 75, 73, ...

Comment: You number sequence is asymmetrical. Did you mean for the first gap to be **12** and not **3**?

Comment: The [second example](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sum-every-nth-row.html) you looked at should work fine.  How did you try to adapt it to your worksheet?  For your second question, merely use the `Data/Text to columns` wizard with pipe `|` as the delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a cell as a standard non-array formula,

```
=SUM(INDEX(A29:A48*NOT(MOD(ROW($29:$48)-29, 3)), , ))
```

The `ROW($29:$48)-29` is the *position within* A29:A38 and must be expanded if A29:A48 is expanded.